# PHP Code Displayed Instead Of Being Processed?

Tags: php

I have the following HTML/PHP/CSS/JavaScript page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Guestbook</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #titles {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        #charremain {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .tb {
            border-top: #000000 1px solid;
            border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;
            border-left: #000000 1px solid;
            border-right: #000000 1px solid;
            background-color: "#000000";
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
            resize: none;
        }
        .submit {
            background-color: #FFCC99;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        }
        table {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function count(x){
            if(x <= 100) {
                document.getElementById('remain').innerHTML = 100 - x;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(form){
            if(form.post.value == "" || form.name.value == ""){
                alert("Please fill in all fields");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor='#FFFCC'>
    <div id='titles' align='center'>
        <form action='test.php' method='POST' onSubmit='return validate(this);'>
        Submit a post: <br \>
        <textarea id='post' class='tb' cols='25' rows='3' name='post' maxLength='100' onKeyUp="count(this.value.length)"></textarea>
        <p id='charremain'>Characters Remaining: <span id='remain'>100</span></p>
        Your name: <input class='tb' type='text' name='name' id='name'><br \>
        <input class='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'><br \>
        </form>
        <br \><br \>
        <H2>Current Posts:</H2>
    </div>
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Could not connect to localhost, check connection!");
        mysql_select_db('test') or die("Could not find database");

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
        $sqlCnt = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($sqlCnt != 0) {
            echo "<table align='center'>
                  <tr><td><u><H4>Message</H4></u></td>
                  <td><u><H4>Poster</H4></u></td></tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row['message'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['poster']
                echo "</td></tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div align='center'>Sorry, no posts found!</div>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Instead of proceeding to the while() loop, the webpage displays everything after , when it should be processing it. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I added the missing semicolon, but no luck. It is an HTML file, and here is a screenshot of what I see:

http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/9867/phpx.png

**Update 2:**
The `else` section of the `if()` statement is working, but when the `$sqlCount != 0` the code is not processed. Everything after the `</tr>` statement on the 3rd line of the first `echo` statement is echoed out, beginning with the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Please clarify "the webpage displays everything after". What is "everything"? Are you seeing PHP code in your web browser?

Comment: Is this a .php file? Also, you are missing a semicolon on `echo $row['poster']`.

Comment: If you look at the source of the page, do you see the starting `<?php` in there?

Comment: Random note: Please use slashes, not backslahes, so that's <br />, not <br \>. In fact, <br /> isn't even valid here. This is HTML, <br /> is only correct in XHTML. So just use <br>. Oh, and for the love of all that is holy, please [do not use the horrible ``or die`` construct](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)...

Comment: @Jason: when you say it is an html file, does the filename perhaps not end in `.php`?

Comment: @Wrikken it is a `.html` file, but I've never had a problem embedding PHP into HTML before.

Comment: @Jason: well, you have now. Parsing `.html` files for PHP is not the default behavior of a webserver (although it can be confugured to do it). Just rename it to `whateveryourfilenameis.php`.

Comment: @Wrikken ok that worked, but now when the `while()` loop is initiated, the php code is echoed out on the screen. It appears that PHP is having a hard time echoing out the HTML `<table>` tags

Comment: @Jason: then PHP is not on your server. Please look at the _source_ of the resulting HTML in a browser (right click, show source): I'll bet good money _none_ of the PHP code is run.

Comment: @Wrikken the source shows the HTML that should be echoed out, but the webpage displays portions of the PHP script itself.

Comment: @Jason: and since you're new, and just to make sure for everybody: you _are_ looking at it through a _webserver_ are you? You're not just putting looking at a local file in the browser?

Comment: I'm running it through XAMPP, hence the 'localhost' connection. The problem is solved though, instead of putting the `</table>` tag outside of the PHP script, I moved it to outside the `while()` loop. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your file name ends with an extension that is valid for PHP scripts (eg: .php).

Also ensure that your webserver (Apache, etc) is loading the PHP module.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it:

```
echo $row['poster']
```

is missing the final semicolon.

Comment: You probably have ``display_errors`` disabled or ``error_reporting`` set to 0. It's best to enable ``display_errors`` and use ``error_reporting(E_ALL)`` when developing code. Makes catching errors *much* easier.

Comment: Of course. In PHP error handling, pretty much everything is possible. Except displaying errors in a sane manner that is :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: how would you like to see it (aside from the usual PHP newbee misconfiguration issues of course)?

Comment: Well, that's a topic for a whole discussion and *far* beyond the scope of these comments :-) Not to mention it's already past my bedtime :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are Apache be sure to check your php.ini for error reporting and add:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

- display_errors (we want it to be On or 1)
- display_startup_errors (we want it to be On or 1)
- log_errors (we want it to be On or 1)
- error_log (it should be anything but undefined)
- error_reporting (it should be 2047 or larger)

It'll make debugging a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when requesting a localhost php file through a relative path in AS3, then I used the full URL path and it worked.